# Line to Line voltage in a three phase circuit with three loads

Tags: voltage, three-phase, voltage-measurement, capacitive, inductive

So the first load is a balanced, purely resistive one. The second one is unbalanced, and the third one is balanced. Diagram looks like this

[image]

For the first load, I'm expecting to get line to line voltages 120° out of phase from each other (angles 30°, -90° and 150°) My results confirm this. However, I'm also getting that the voltage for the second load (the unbalanced one, with inductive and capacitive charges) has basically the same phases, and so does the third load (I guess it makes more sense because it is balanced, but its charges have inductive values so wouldn't that change the angles a bit still?)

Can someone explain why is this happening? Are my results wrong? I expect the phases of the voltages for the second and third load to be different because of their non-exclusively resistive charges.

Here are my results

[image]

First one is for the first load, second one for the second load...

Generators are 120° out of phase with each other.

Comment: What are the impedances you assumed?

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that the line impedances (\$Z_{L1}\$, \$Z_{L2}\$, and \$Z_{L3}\$) from one load to the next are other than purely resistive, you can expect the voltages at each load to exhibit a phase shift with respect to the source.  But if the line impedances are purely resistive, then there will be no such phase shift in voltage.  Typically the magnitudes of the line impedances are not great anyway, so the voltage drop across them will be small, and the phase shift in voltage is likely to be negligible.

The loads themselves will exhibit phase shift in the *currents* that flow through them if they have capacitive or inductive characteristics.